# How to enable usb debugging and install an apk to an android device with non-functioning display?

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen

The display of my Xperia z3 is non-functioning(i.e. all I can see is a black screen) after an accidental damage due to water-insertion. But all other parts are working fine. The screen responses to touch, I can hear the touch sounds and I can click photographs as well with the camera key.

After connecting the phone with USB cable to my ubuntu laptop, I can browse through the internal storage files on the phone and locate the newly created image files as I click new photographs and take screen-shots. But I can't open any files(images/audio/videos) with errors like "couldn't load image" and "couldn't determine type of stream". However, I'm able to copy new files to the internal storage.

I want to install some screencasting application like vysor on my phone so that I can access it using my laptop. I know this can be done using adb commands but the problem here is that USB debugging is not enabled on my phone and hence I can't find it on the list of adb devices.

Is there any workaround for such situation?

Comment: see the [broken screen tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) and other questions therein

Comment: So I guess the question here is how to enable USB debugging without a functional screen. Because from then on by using Vysor you can do the rest.

Comment: If the device is online and Playstore activated, you can trigger an app installation via https://play.google.com

Comment: yeah, primarily that's what I'm trying to do. @papakias

Comment: Unfortunately, the device is not online :( @Robert

Comment: I've heard that for some devices, if you put them in recovery mode, they can be seen by pc's without usb debugging turned on. I don't know though if you can install apk's or see the screen somehow :( It's just something that I remember I read somewhere.